# How do I find the all of the sibling's children records?

Tags: c#, linq

I am stuck and need a linq statement that would do the following.

Situation:
Store has a collection of Departments Departments have a collection orders.

```
  StoreID:1
     DepartmentID:D1,
        OrderID:O1,
        OrderID:O2,
        OrderID:O3,
     DepartmentID:D2,
        OrderID:O4,
        OrderID:O5
     DepartmentID:D3,
        OrderID:O6,
        OrderID:O7
```

If given a DepartmentId find the Store associated to it.  With that store get me all the orders associated for all departments associated to the store.

If I have the id for a Department say D2 in the example above.  I want all the orders for for All departments associated to the Store for D2.

What would the linq statement look like?

Comment: Are the same departments relate to multiple stores? and can you add any extended example of data set.

Comment: No each department is only related to one store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have a model of classes like this:

```
public class Store
{
  public string StoreID{get;set;}
  public IList<Department> Departments{get;set;}
}

public class Department
{
  public string DepartmentID{get;set;}
  public Store Store{get;set;}
  public IList<Order> Orders{get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
  public string OrderID{get;set;}
  public Department Department{get;set;}
}
```

You need to use the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) extension method to  flatten the sequences of `Orders` of each `Department` into one sequence:

```
// Departments is your data source
//Find the department
var department= Departments.FirstOrDefault(d=>d.DepartmentID=="D2");
if(department!=null)
{
  //Get all the orders from that Store
  var orders= department.Store.Departments.SelectMany(d=>d.Orders); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well.You can verify this in LinqPad for proof of concept.

```
void Main()
{
    var storeDepartments = new List<Department>();

    storeDepartments.Add(new Department { DepartmentId= 1, OrdersId= new List<int>(){1,2,3}});
    storeDepartments.Add(new Department { DepartmentId= 2, OrdersId= new List<int>(){4,5}});
    storeDepartments.Add(new Department { DepartmentId= 3, OrdersId= new List<int>(){6,7}});

    var stores = new List<Store>();

    var myStore = new Store {
        StoreId= 1,
        Departments= storeDepartments
    };

    stores.Add(myStore);

    var store = stores.Find(s => s.Departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 2) != null);

    var orders = store.Departments.SelectMany(d => d.OrdersId).ToList();

    orders.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Store {
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department {
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrdersId { get; set; }
}
```